# How to resolve the following exception while excuting explain plan in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, sql-execution-plan

I am executing explain plan for query in DB2 database. I am getting following error. I am clue less about the issue.
Can some body help me how to resolve this issue?

Below is the error message

"ERROR [58004] [IBM][DB2/NT] SQL0901N  The SQL statement or command failed because of a database system error. (Reason "Parameter marker in literal replaced statement".)"

Comment: Does this happen for any database or a specific database?

Comment: It is happening to this specific database. Earlier it was working fine. It is happening from past couple of days. There is no changes made to schema

Comment: Check the db2diag file of the corresponding instance. You can have more explicit messages there.

Comment: Without seeing the statement that fails, it's very unlikely we can give useful guesses. You can see the code and can't figure it out. It's a **lot** harder for us without the code.